# Error occured while evaluating nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the code

```
if !params[:ratings].nil? 
    params[:ratings].each_key do |r|
        @selected_ratings << r
        @movies << Movie.where('rating = :rating', :rating => r)
        @sort = params[:sort]
      end 
elsif
    @selected_ratings = @all_ratings
    @movies = Movie.order(@sort)
    @sort = params[:sort]
end
```

This is the error

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<
```

EDIT : 
The problem is that i want to concat the values in my instance variable movies and for that i am trying to use "<<". When i use the "=" instead of "<<" then it only considers movie according to the last rating value.

EDIT 2 (description ):

Maybe i should explained a bit more about the problem. So the thing is
that that i have a movie table in the database with properties such as
titile, rating etc. Now i have a check box of ratings like
['G','PG','R']. When a user selects one or more of these check boxes
then i have those in my params[ratings]. For example if he chooses 'R'
and 'G' then my params[rating] would be ['G', 'R']. Now, what i want to
do is to have only those movies which have the following ratings in my
@movies and for that i am trying to use

```
    @movies << Movie.where('rating = :rating', :rating => r)
```

but it fails
I have tried to use

```
    @movies = Movie.where('rating = :rating', :rating => r)
```

But in this case i have movies selected with respect to one particular
rating for example only 'R' rated movies are shown.

Also i cannot do @movies = []
because i have movies with properties such as title etc...

One more thing to add, i am new to web and database related stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to initialize each array before adding something in it.